# Eliminate creating object reference for calling static methods

Tags: java, static-methods, smartgwt

I have a class which is having static methods, So i am calling the static methods without creating object reference for it.
like below:

```
public Class DateChooser extends VLayout implements com.smartgwt.client.widgets.events.HasDataChangedHandlers {

 public static native void changeAutoChildDefaults(String autoChildName, Canvas defaults) /*-{
        $wnd.isc.DateChooser.changeDefaults(autoChildName + "Defaults", defaults.@com.smartgwt.client.widgets.Canvas::getConfig()());
    }-*/;

}


public class Myclass{
 DateItem dateField;// Smart Gwt class
 dateField = new DateItem("counterDateItem","");
DateChooser dateChooser = new DateChooser();  // Smart Gwt class
dateChooser.changeAutoChildDefaults("hideBtn", canvas); // calling static method

dateField.setDateChooser(dateChooser);
}
```

how can i eliminate creating the object for calling static methods in above case.

Comment: Java basics: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Comment: I don't know the people are here down vote for the questions. Please let me know the reason before downvote

Comment: Is that the exact MyClass that you are using? Because you can not call methods (`dateChooser.changeAutoChildDefaults`, `dateField.setDateChooser`) the way you did in class body (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6151218/method-calls-inside-a-java-class)

Comment: No its not like that, I have some other code along with it. DateItem and DateChooser is Smart gwt classes.

Comment: Hello all, Please carefully look into query first, its not like normal java basic, The classes are smart gwt classes. Please don't downvote without observing carefully.

Answer (score 3):

Call it directly. With static methods, you don't need to create a reference anymore.

```
DateChooser.changeAutoChildDefaults();
```

Comment: Thank you @J.Lucky, I know the above solution but i want that object to set it in my object. Please look at code once again

Comment: @majji, then maybe your `changeAutoChildDefaults()` shouldn't be a `static` method?

Comment: it is a static method which is Smart Gwt method not my own method